# SQLite less than or equal to only returning equal results

Tags: r, sqlite

I am working on a large database that contains wine names, prices, etc... 
I want to query a table for all chardonnay that is $10 or less per bottle, but I keep getting results that are $10.

```
dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT Name, Price FROM Wines
       WHERE price<=10
       AND name LIKE '%Chardonnay%'")
```

If I query only for Chardonnay I can see there are some under $10

```
895                                                  Chardonnay    12
896                                          Reserve Chardonnay    16
897                                                  Chardonnay    10
898                                      Wyckoff Vyd Chardonnay    21
899                                          Reserve Chardonnay    29
900                                             Fume Chardonnay     9
901                                 Barrel Fermented Chardonnay    13
902                                          Reserve Chardonnay    11
903                                                  Chardonnay    10
904                                 Woodburne CuvÃ©e Chardonnay    14
905                                                  Chardonnay     7
```

When I run the above query I get this:

```
50                               Chardonnay    10
51                               Chardonnay    10 
52                               Chardonnay    10
53                               Chardonnay    10
54                               Chardonnay    10
55                               Chardonnay    10
```

All 55 results had 10 as the price

I feel like it has to be a formatting issue, but I haven't been able to get it right

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT DISTINCT typeof(Price) FROM Wines`?

Answer (score 2):

SQlite uses dynamic typing and you can insert strings into int columns. Likely your prices are inserted as strings or your price columns is not a number (integer, float) column. Make sure the column is of the right type and your prices values are inserted as the right type.

Comment: Thanks, it was all text. From what I could find there is no good way to change the data type in SQLite, is that correct? I changed the values on the original dataframe and then reloaded it into my dataframe and the query is working properly now.

Comment: There's indeed no good way to change the data type, you need to drop and recreate the table.